# Eloquent error using with and select together. Segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache, laravel, eloquent, lumen

When performing `select` and `with` in one query builder there's no server error. I just get the following message: `<domain> page isnt working. <domain> didn't send any data.`

When I check in /var/log/apache2/error.log there is a log of:

`child pid 1948 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

I've tried using query scopes as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702492/laravel-eloquent-with-and-select-conflict-with-each-other) **eg**

```
$posts = Post::with(['image' => function($query){
  $query->select('id');
}])->select('id')->get();
```

If I change `get()` to `toSql()` it only outputs `select id from posts`;

I've also tried removing the `select` and passing columns to `get()` with no luck.

Further investigation:

I've tried setting up GDP to debug apache core dumps, but no dumps seem to get created.

I've since setup xdebug and followed the function stack to it's [death here at](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L640) `function loadRelation()` inside `Eloquent\Builder.php`.

Prior to this it calls [eagerLoadRelations(array $models)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L609) and gets all Post models correctly as a collection of posts with only id attributes, yet on the first iteration of of loading the image relation it dies on

`call_user_func($constraints, $relation);`

any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault sounds a bit weird, but try adding `user_id` to the select so it can do the join e.g.:

```
$posts = Post::with(['image' => function($query){
  $query->select('id', 'user_id');
}])->select('id')->get();
```